# How do you disable "suggest completions while typing" autocomplete feature while editing Applescript in Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator, script, auto-complete

I think in a recent update to Ventura they added an autocomplete feature to Applescript editing. In Script Editor, there's a setting to enable or disable "suggest completions while typing". It's nominally a useless feature and serves to only get in the way (mostly because I can't figure out how to accept or reject a suggestion), so I have it disabled in Script Editor.

BUT...when editing Applescript blocks in Automator it tries to do the same thing, albeit it's somehow even more buggy and in the way. It actively interrupts typing (sometimes without even making an actual suggestion) and results in gibberish. Is there a way to tell Automator to stop doing it? Naturally, Automator doesn't have a settings menu, so the assumption is the answer is "no". This is unfortunate because it really makes it impossible to edit Applescript in the Automator environment.

Someone on the Apple forums also reported [Why is gibberish being typed into Automator script?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254514861)
but there was no resolution, only snide remarks that it "couldn't happen" and it's not a bug. Which I guess is technically true, this behavior is in fact the result of an intentional "feature". You can tell in the picture OP posted that autocomplete is interfering because of the shadow "e" in "We".

Any thoughts?